# How do I run Docker containers as a Active Directory-domain user (SSSD)? ("unable to find user")

Tags: debian, docker, samba4, sssd

I am running several Samba-shares on a dedicated Debian 9.6 machine joined to an AD-domain (Zentyal with SMB 4).

I am using a pretty straight-forward SSSD installation that has so far worked out perfectly for our needs.

I want to set [Ambar](https://ambar.cloud/) up so that the various domain users could search documents on the aforementioned Samba-shares. However, I only want Ambar to crawl "public" documents, and nothing from private/"management" folders.

I've changed the docker-compose.yml file so that Docker will spawn the containers it needs as the user **crawler**, but when I run `docker-compose up -d` I get the following error:

`ERROR: for Shared-folder  Cannot start service Shared-folder: linux spec user: unable to find user crawler: no matching entries in passwd file`

Editing the `/etc/passwd` file manually does not help here. I still get the same error.

This is how the relevant docker-compose.yml configuration looks like:

```
Shared-folder:
  depends_on:
    serviceapi:
      condition: service_healthy
  image: ambar/ambar-local-crawler
  restart: always
  networks:
    - internal_network
    expose:
    - "8082"
  environment:
    - name=Shared-folder
    - ignoreExtensions=.{exe,dll,rar,s,so}
    - apiUrl=http://serviceapi:8081
  user: crawler
  volumes:
    - /shared/Shared-folder:/usr/data
```

Please observe that if I remove the line `user: crawler`, everything works as expected (and `root` crawls all of my documents).

Here is my `/etc/sssd/sssd.conf`-file:

```
[sssd]
services = nss, pam
config_file_version = 2
domains = MY.COMPANY.COM

[domain/MY.COMPANY.COM]
id_provider = ad
access_provider = ad
ad_gpo_map_interactive = +cron
dyndns_update_ptr=false

# Use this if users are being logged in at /.
# This example specifies /home/DOMAIN-FQDN/user as $HOME.  Use with pam_mkhomedir.so
override_homedir = /home/%u
ldap_idmap_autorid_compat = True
```

And here's my `/etc/pam.d/common-session`:

```
#
# /etc/pam.d/common-session - session-related modules common to all services
#
# This file is included from other service-specific PAM config files,
# and should contain a list of modules that define tasks to be performed
# at the start and end of sessions of *any* kind (both interactive and
# non-interactive).
#
# As of pam 1.0.1-6, this file is managed by pam-auth-update by default.
# To take advantage of this, it is recommended that you configure any
# local modules either before or after the default block, and use
# pam-auth-update to manage selection of other modules.  See
# pam-auth-update(8) for details.

# here are the per-package modules (the "Primary" block)
session [default=1]                     pam_permit.so
# here's the fallback if no module succeeds
session requisite                       pam_deny.so
# prime the stack with a positive return value if there isn't one already;
# this avoids us returning an error just because nothing sets a success code
# since the modules above will each just jump around
session required                        pam_permit.so
# and here are more per-package modules (the "Additional" block)
session required        pam_unix.so
session required        pam_mkhomedir.so skel=/etc/skel/ umask=0066
session optional                        pam_winbind.so
session optional                        pam_sss.so
session optional        pam_systemd.so
# end of pam-auth-update config
```

Please let me know if any configs would be helpful! My guess is that `smb.conf` is not that relevant in this case, and that there might be some way to tell Docker to just trust PAM?

Answer (score 0):

The domain configuration in `sssd.conf` doesn't have `use_fully_qualified_names = False`. Without this, you may be expected to use fully qualified names (e.g. `crawler@MY.COMPANY.COM`). This is not strictly necessary to solve your problem but I find it useful if the machine is only referencing one domain. Alternatively:

- You might try specifying the fully qualified name for the user in `docker-compose.yaml` (i.e. `user: crawler@MY.COMPANY.COM`). I have not tried this so I can't confirm it works as expected.
- You could use the uid of the user instead of the name. This is the method I use so I can confirm it works just fine. You can retrieve the uid by running `id <username>` (making sure you use the format corresponding to your `use_fully_qualified_names` setting).

In any case, if you can't retrieve the uid of your user by running `id <username>` then your issue likely lies with your SSSD configuration rather than the docker configuration.